# HashMaps with Comparable keys not working as expected

Tags: java, hashmap

We're facing weird issues with how HashMap behaves.

When HashMap keys implement Comparable interface but compareTo implementation is inconsistent with equals then HashMaps:

- grow much larger then they are supposed to grow
- they contain several instances of equal elements
- values attached to those elements might differ
- get(key) result depends on which key is used (even if the keys are equal according to equals method).

I've created a small test to reproduce the problem (see below).

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HashMapTest {
private static final char MIN_NAME = 'A'; 
private static final char MAX_NAME = 'K'; 
private static final int EXPECTED_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS = MAX_NAME - MIN_NAME + 1; 

private HashMap<Person, Integer> personToAgeMap; 

HashMapTest(){
    personToAgeMap = new HashMap(); 
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    HashMapTest objHashMap = new HashMapTest();
    System.out.println("Initial Size of Map: " + objHashMap.getPersonToAgeMap().size());
    objHashMap.whenOverridingEqualElements_thenSizeOfTheMapIsStable();
    objHashMap.whenGettingElementUsingPersonOfAge1_thenOverridenValuesAreReturned();
    objHashMap.whenGettingElementUsingPersonOfAge100_thenOverridenValuesAreReturned();
    objHashMap.whenGettingElementUsingPersonOfAge50_thenOverridenValuesAreReturned();
    objHashMap.whenGettingElementUsingPersonOfAgeMinus1_thenOverridenValuesAreReturned();
}

public HashMap<Person, Integer> getPersonToAgeMap(){
    return personToAgeMap;
}

public void whenOverridingEqualElements_thenSizeOfTheMapIsStable() { 
    System.out.println("Adding elements with age 1..");
    putAllPeopleWithAge(personToAgeMap, 1);
    System.out.println(personToAgeMap);
    System.out.println("Expected Number Of elements: " + EXPECTED_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS+ "\nActual Number of elements: "+personToAgeMap.size());

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Overwriting map, with value 100..");
    putAllPeopleWithAge(personToAgeMap, 100);
    System.out.println(personToAgeMap);
    System.out.println("Expected Number Of elements: " + EXPECTED_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS+ "\nActual Number of elements: "+personToAgeMap.size());
    System.out.println();
} 


public void whenGettingElementUsingPersonOfAge1_thenOverridenValuesAreReturned() {      
    useAgeToCheckAllHashMapValuesAre(1, 100); 
} 


public void whenGettingElementUsingPersonOfAge100_thenOverridenValuesAreReturned() {  
    useAgeToCheckAllHashMapValuesAre(100, 100); 
} 

public void whenGettingElementUsingPersonOfAge50_thenOverridenValuesAreReturned() {  
    useAgeToCheckAllHashMapValuesAre(50, 100); 
} 


public void whenGettingElementUsingPersonOfAgeMinus1_thenOverridenValuesAreReturned() {        
    useAgeToCheckAllHashMapValuesAre(-10, 100); 
}

private void useAgeToCheckAllHashMapValuesAre(int age, Integer expectedValue) { 
    System.out.println("Checking the values corresponding to age = " + age);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

    int count = countAllPeopleUsingAge(personToAgeMap, age); 
    System.out.println("Count of People with age " + age+" =" + count);

    if (EXPECTED_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS != count) { 
        sb.append("Size of the map ").append(" is wrong: ") 
            .append("expected <").append(EXPECTED_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS).append("> actual <").append(count).append(">.\n"); 
    } 

    for (char name = MIN_NAME; name <= MAX_NAME; name++) { 
        Person key = new Person(name, age); 
        Integer value = personToAgeMap.get(key); 
        if (!expectedValue.equals(value)) { 
            sb.append("Unexpected value for ").append(key).append(": ") 
            .append("expected <").append(expectedValue).append("> actual <").append(value).append(">.\n"); 
        } 
     } 

    if (sb.length() > 0) { 
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    } 
   } 

 void putAllPeopleWithAge(Map<Person, Integer> map, int age) { 
    for (char name = MIN_NAME; name <= MAX_NAME; name++) { 
        map.put(new Person(name, age), age); 
    } 
   } 

 int countAllPeopleUsingAge(Map<Person, Integer> map, int age) { 
    int counter = 0; 
    for (char name = MIN_NAME; name <= MAX_NAME; name++) { 
        if (map.containsKey(new Person(name, age))) { 
            counter++; 
        } 
    } 
    return counter; 
   } 

 String getAllPeopleUsingAge(Map<Person, Integer> map, int age) { 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    for (char name = MIN_NAME; name <= MAX_NAME; name++) { 
        Person key = new Person(name, age); 
        sb.append(key).append('=').append(map.get(key)).append('\n'); 
    } 
    return sb.toString(); 
   } 

 class Person implements Comparable<Person> { 
    char name; 
    int age; 

    public Person(char name, int age) { 
        this.name = name; 
        this.age = age; 
    } 

    //Making sure all elements end up in the very same bucket 
    //Nothing wrong with it except performance... 
    @Override 
    public int hashCode() { 
        return 0; 
    } 

    //equals is only by name 
    @Override 
    public boolean equals(Object other) { 
        Person otherPerson = (Person)other; 
        return this.name == otherPerson.name; 
     } 

     public String toString() { 
        return name + "[age=" + age + "]"; 
     } 

    //comparing by age 
    //NOTE: compareTo is inconsistent with equals which should be OK in non-sorted collections 
    //https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html 
    @Override 
    public int compareTo(Person other) { 
        return this.age - other.age; 
      } 
   } 
   }
```

**Expected Output**

```
  Initial Size of Map: 0
 Adding elements with age 1..
{K[age=1]=1, J[age=1]=1, I[age=1]=1, H[age=1]=1, G[age=1]=1, F[age=1]=1,    E[age=1]=1, D[age=1]=1, C[age=1]=1, B[age=1]=1, A[age=1]=1}
Expected Number Of elements: 11
Actual Number of elements: 11

Overwriting map, with value 100..
{K[age=1]=100, J[age=1]=100, I[age=1]=100, H[age=1]=100, G[age=1]=100,  F[age=1]=100, E[age=1]=100, D[age=1]=100, C[age=1]=100, B[age=1]=100, A[age=1]=100}
 Expected Number Of elements: 11
 Actual Number of elements: 11

 Checking the values corresponding to age = 1
 Count of People with age 1 =11
 Checking the values corresponding to age = 100
 Count of People with age 100 =11
 Checking the values corresponding to age = 50
 Count of People with age 50 =11
 Checking the values corresponding to age = -10
 Count of People with age -10 =11
```

**Actual OutPut**

```
Initial Size of Map: 0
Adding elements with age 1..
{I[age=1]=1, A[age=1]=1, B[age=1]=1, C[age=1]=1, D[age=1]=1, E[age=1]=1,  F[age=1]=1, G[age=1]=1, H[age=1]=1, J[age=1]=1, K[age=1]=1}
Expected Number Of elements: 11
Actual Number of elements: 11

Overwriting map, with value 100..
{I[age=1]=100, A[age=1]=1, B[age=1]=100, C[age=1]=1, D[age=1]=100, A[age=100]=100, C[age=100]=100, E[age=100]=100, H[age=100]=100, J[age=100]=100, K[age=100]=100, F[age=100]=100, G[age=100]=100, E[age=1]=1, F[age=1]=1, G[age=1]=1, H[age=1]=1, J[age=1]=1, K[age=1]=1}
  Expected Number Of elements: 11
  Actual Number of elements: 19

  Checking the values corresponding to age = 1
  Count of People with age 1 =11
  Unexpected value for E[age=1]: expected <100> actual <1>.
  Unexpected value for F[age=1]: expected <100> actual <1>.
 Unexpected value for G[age=1]: expected <100> actual <1>.
 Unexpected value for J[age=1]: expected <100> actual <1>.
  Unexpected value for K[age=1]: expected <100> actual <1>.

  Checking the values corresponding to age = 100
 Count of People with age 100 =10
 Size of the map  is wrong: expected <11> actual <10>.
 Unexpected value for B[age=100]: expected <100> actual <null>.

 Checking the values corresponding to age = 50
 Count of People with age 50 =5
 Size of the map  is wrong: expected <11> actual <5>.
 Unexpected value for B[age=50]: expected <100> actual <null>.
 Unexpected value for E[age=50]: expected <100> actual <null>.
 Unexpected value for F[age=50]: expected <100> actual <null>.
 Unexpected value for G[age=50]: expected <100> actual <null>.
 Unexpected value for J[age=50]: expected <100> actual <null>.
 Unexpected value for K[age=50]: expected <100> actual <null>.

 Checking the values corresponding to age = -10
 Count of People with age -10 =4
 Size of the map  is wrong: expected <11> actual <4>.
 Unexpected value for A[age=-10]: expected <100> actual <1>.
 Unexpected value for B[age=-10]: expected <100> actual <null>.
 Unexpected value for C[age=-10]: expected <100> actual <1>.
 Unexpected value for D[age=-10]: expected <100> actual <null>.
 Unexpected value for E[age=-10]: expected <100> actual <1>.
 Unexpected value for F[age=-10]: expected <100> actual <null>.
 Unexpected value for G[age=-10]: expected <100> actual <null>.  
 Unexpected value for H[age=-10]: expected <100> actual <null>.
 Unexpected value for J[age=-10]: expected <100> actual <null>.
  Unexpected value for K[age=-10]: expected <100> actual <null>.
```

Comment: `compareTo implementation is inconsistent with equals` if you implement `boolean compareTo(Object o)` incorrectly, you may run the risk of something behind the scenes attempting to sort based on compareTo and ending up sorting incorrectly/duplicating elements in sets

Comment: Comparable should be consistent with Equals and Hashcode... It's a bad practice if they are not and can lead to strange results. If you have to compare your objects with another value, use a Comparator instead.

Comment: Also note that in general incorrect implementations of interfaces will probably lead to incorrect results from things using that interface

Comment: //NOTE: compareTo is inconsistent with equals which should be OK in non-sorted collections 
    //https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: Can you create an MCVE? (*Minimal*, Complete, and Verifiable example, with the emphasis on "Minimal", you can make a much shorter test than this) http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt This is actually a rather difficult question to produce an MCVE for, since it depends on internal hash collisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Java 8, an optimization was added to `HashMap` to deal with collisions when keys are `Comparable`:

> To ameliorate impact, when keys are `java.lang.Comparable`, this class may use comparison order among keys to help break ties.

If your keys have a natural ordering that is inconsistent with `equals()`, any number of odd things may happen, and in this case it looks like the map is trying to keep track of keys using the natural ordering.

Comment: Bang on target I am using java 8 as well... :) Thanks a lot chrylis

Comment: To ameliorate impact of what?  Does that mean they did something even worse than breaking `HashMap`?

Comment: If a type can be the same according to `compareTo` while not with `equals` you are alright, so long as if they the same with `equals` then they are also with `compareTo`. The standard example is `BigDecimal` with `1.0` and `1.00` are not the same with `equals` but are with `compareTo`.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your unexpected results.  Then I removed `Comparable` from `Person` and all the checks passed.  Then I restored `Comparable`, switched to OpenJDK 7, and all the checks passed.  Just to be sure, I switched back to Oracle Java 8, and again got your unexpected result.  Evidently, Oracle has done something "clever" with `HashMap` in Java 8.  Keep up the good work, Oracle.

Comment: So much for backward compatibility and write once/run everywhere :-(